# How to center a Widget vertically in PreferredSizeWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to center a Text vertically in the `bottom:` Sektion of my `AppBar`.

Some things I allready tried are:
1. wrap the Text in a `Center(...)` Widget
2. wrap the Text in a `Column(...)` and use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`

The `bottom:` Sektion is a [PreferredSizeWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PreferredSizeWidget-class.html) and does not provide anything to format a Widget.

```
appBar: new AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Settings Icon");
          },
        ),
      ],
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(130.0, 130.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'N/A',      
           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I have have found this issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16262 where the Text was centered but the reproduce code did not worked out for me.

The Text should me somewhere like the red line is (see Image)

[image: AppBar]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PreferredSizeWidget` does not impose a size constraint on its child, so you must wrap the `Column` in a widget with defined height in order to add alignment.

Also, `mainAxisAlignment` should be used, since this is the vertical alignment in a `Column`.

```
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(130.0, 130.0),
    child: Container(
      height: 130,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            'N/A',      
        ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```